# Code that hugs commands between save and retrieve mechanism

Tags: c, arm, stm32, cpu-registers

Recently I am implementing the internal peripherals of STM32F0 family mcu in a c library.

While I was looking at how ST managed to do the same with their HAL library I stepped into this piece of code...

```
  1 /*--------------------- EXTI Mode Configuration ------------------------*/
  2 /* Configure the External Interrupt or event for the current IO */
  3 if((GPIO_Init->Mode & EXTI_MODE) == EXTI_MODE) 
  4 {
  5  /* Enable SYSCFG Clock */
  6  __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();

  7  temp = SYSCFG->EXTICR[position >> 2];
  8  CLEAR_BIT(temp, (0x0FU) << (4U * (position & 0x03U)));
  9  SET_BIT(temp, (GPIO_GET_INDEX(GPIOx)) << (4U * (position & 0x03U)));
  10 SYSCFG->EXTICR[position >> 2] = temp;

  11 /* Clear EXTI line configuration */
  12  temp = EXTI->IMR;
  13  CLEAR_BIT(temp, (uint32_t)iocurrent);
  14  if((GPIO_Init->Mode & GPIO_MODE_IT) == GPIO_MODE_IT)
  15  {
  16   SET_BIT(temp, iocurrent); 
  17  }
  18  EXTI->IMR = temp;
```

What I am trying to understand is **why** the pair commands in lines **7-10** and **12-18** are used. **Why** are there? Why store something then write it and then retrieve it from memory discarted wroten content?
Is it about multitasking and race conditions? I do not fully understand!

Comment: *Why store something then write it and then retrieve it from memory discarted wroten content?* what? Can you please rewrite your question so that we can understand what you mean and not guess? Also what does *to hug a command* mean?

Comment: this was just asked and answered recently.

Comment: very standard to read-modify-write a registers contents so that some percentage of the register can be completely changed to the desired value in what the control register sees as a single write.  anything else can bring chaos to what the register controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used for speed optimization and to avoid unwanted states in memory-mapped registers.
Imagine some example memory-mapped variable EXT->ABC. Imagine such exaggerated example situation:

- We have some hardware memory address that is accessible via memory-mapped EXT->ABC variable
- We know that bit 1 is set and bit 2 is cleared in EXT->ABC
- We want to clear bit 1 and set bit 2 and leave all other bits unchanged in EXT->ABC
- Hardware doesn't allow bit 1 and bit 2 in EXT->ABC register to be both cleared or both set. Such states are forbidden and may result in undefined behavior (that means in ANY behavior, for example software reset).
- Reading and writing to EXT->ABC register is very very slow.

If we operate on EXT->ABC variable directly:

```
CLEAR_BIT(EXT->ABC, 1); // expands to: EXT->ABC = EXT->ABC & ~1;
SET_BIT(EXT->ABC, 2);   // expands to: EXT->ABC = EXT->ABC | 2;
```

this will result in a forbidden state in between the two lines, as bit 1 and bit 2 will be set. Also, in these 2 lines, EXTI->IMR is accessed 4 times.
To resolve this, we need to store the value in EXTI->IMR register somewhere, modify needed bits, and then write the modified value to EXTI->IMR register. So we will:

```
uint32_t temp;
temp = EXT->ABC; // store
CLEAR_BIT(temp, 1);
SET_BIT(temp, 2);
EXT->ABC = temp; // write
```

We read *once* from a memory-mapped variable, modify&play with the value, do whatever we want. After that, we write *once* to memory-mapped variable. That way EXT->ABC register is touched only twice and code is written safely, so that no undefined/forbidden/unwanted states occur.
For example: as for lines 7-10: to access `SYSCFG->EXTICR[position >> 2U]` you need multiple cpu operations (calculate `position >> 2U`, multiple by `sizeof(SYSCFG->EXTICR)`, add to `SYSCFG->EXTICR` address, dereference). Maybe it was developer intention to execute these lines faster. Or you need to clear bits `0x0F<<(4*(position&0x03)` when writting to `(GPIO_GET_INDEX(GPIOx))<<(4*position&0x03)`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

It is to make the operations "atomic". All changes to the registers in one write operation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything strange:

Lines 7-10 and 12-18 copy what seems to be the contents of a register to a local variable, do some operation on it and then store the result back to the original register.

The reason why this may happen are multiple, but my guess is that the author of the code did not want the MCU to be in an intermediate state while tinkering with the registers.

For example, what happens to the core after line 8 but before line 9?

Comment: *but my guess is that the author of the code did not want the MCU to be in an intermediate state while tinkering with the registers.* not only that, but when you are initializing certain units (like uart, i2c, etc.) you sometimes have precise order into which some bits have to be set and cleared.